# OS portable code for referring template files

Tags: go

Below is the code, that runs in windows:

```
wd, err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

t, err := template.ParseFiles(wd + "\\src\\html\\index.html")
```

---

which fails in Linux due to backslash(`\`)

How to make this code portable across OS?

Comment: `Package filepath implements utility routines for manipulating filename paths in a way compatible with the target operating system-defined file paths.` [path/filepath](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/)

Comment: ParseFiles(filepath.Join(wd, filepath.FromSlash("src/html/index/html")))

Comment: IIRC, windows can now handle `/` for paths, too. I've not used windows in years, but I've seen it being used in the wild, so why not try that?

Comment: You also don't need to append `wd` by hand. Any relative (not starting with a slash or drive letter) path is assumed to be rooted in the working directory.

Comment: @Adrian On using `t, err := template.ParseFiles("html/index.html")` I get error: `http: panic serving [::1]:54221: open html/index.html: The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: Based on your quoted code, shouldn't the path be `src/html/index.html` not just `html/index.html`?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, Windows has done so since at least 95/NT4.

Answer (score 1):

In general using [filepath.Join](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Join) is a way to go:

```
path := filepath.Join("separate", "me")
```

But [filepath.FromSlash](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#FromSlash) is much more readable in my opinion:

```
path := filepath.FromSlash("separate/me")
```